# How to enumerate network interfaces and IP address on my mobile device

Tags: codenameone

I am building a codenameone java client to communicate with a Java RMI server.
Can you advise how to enumerate the interfaces and Wi-Fi IP address on my destination mobile device?

I am looking for more details on what codenameone libs to use that provides the usual java.net methods, like
    Enumeration nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets)) {
                String str = displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
                String IP1 = inc.getRowFromDelimitedStringSafe(str, 2, '~');
                System.out.println("IP = "+IP+" str = "+str);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Codename One doesn't support RMI. Mobile devices don't have the network interface API either as a mobile device won't have an ethernet port to choose from.

It's highly recommended you use HTTPS for communication or WebSockets since the mobile devices connect via cellular networks that might fail or filter "odd" traffic.

Comment: Thanks, However, this Mobile device is expected to connect to a local wireless network and communicate VIA sockets to a Socket server on the same network. This app will be used in an environment where Wi-Fi is always available and is capable of working offline. Will not be using the cell network. I want to discover my IP and interface established with Wi-Fi.

Comment: In that case you can use Socket which is pretty much the main use for this API. Notice that the framework is designed for the generic case and not the special case so API's like RMI don't make much sense in the generic case.